# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Со слов президента Российского биржевого союза Гавриленко: «…чтобы закон об инсайде заработал, как на Западе, нужна продолжительная работа целого подразделения в штате ФСФР».
Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Answer (score 1):

Знаки, поставленные Вами, вполне приемлемы. Они оправданы соответствующей интонацией. 
Верен и такой вариант: ***Со слов президента Российского биржевого союза Гавриленко, «…чтобы закон об инсайде заработал, как на Западе, нужна продолжительная работа целого подразделения в штате ФСФР».*** Запятая выделяет вводное словосочетание, указывающее источник сообщения.

Comment: Мне второй вариант нравится больше.

Comment: Мне тоже второй, потому что он безусловный.

Answer (score 0):

Мне тоже нравится более "второй" вариант, но исходя из логики говорящего, полагаю, что запятая перед как - лишняя, т.к. "как на Западе" является обстоятельством образа действия и поэтому не требует обособления.

Здесь очень тонкий момент. Раздичить сравнение и обстоятельство образа действия часто бывает невозможно, хотя какие-то рекомендации можно найти в учебниках.

В данном случае я (глубоко субъективно, разумеется) вижу это так.

"...чтобы закон об инсайде заработал, как на Западе, нужна продолжительная работа..." - "как на Западе" - относится к самому закону, который [у нас] не работает вообще.

"...чтобы закон об инсайде заработал как на Западе, нужна продолжительная работа..." - "как на Западе" относится сказуемому "заработал", сам же закон [у нас] работает, но *не так*, как на Западе.

*Скажите, у всех стал тормозить форум?*

Comment: Да, у меня страничка дольше стала  загружаться. Но у нас скорость маленькая, я на это грешила.